# Transaction successful but ether not transferred to destination account

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, private-blockchain

I am following [this](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-setting-up-a-private-blockchain-67bbb96cf4f1) article and everything works expected but ether is not getting transferred to the to account.Please find the logs below.

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(4, "ether")})
```

above line of code runs and miner also get updated with below log.

```
INFO [09-12|18:03:43.102] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xb7810c410aeff448b7785bdaf3d7929dade567a919b35c8d543aa4d85066d322 recipient=0xf74c6516c4f7c87C663f3AEfcE67D815Fb1BF047
```

But amount after successful transaction always remains zero.

I have searched and applied all the possible workarounds i could find on ethereum stackexchange but nothing helped.

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])

0
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])

5.2175e+22
> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(4, "ether")})
"0x6a66d2dbc1610e20405828fdbfbf7b028ec3ce5d20e3800267e0f99b70be1426"
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
5.2175e+22
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
0
> eth.hashrate
0
> eth.blockNumber
10438

> eth.pendingTransactions
[]
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x6a66d2dbc1610e20405828fdbfbf7b028ec3ce5d20e3800267e0f99b70be1426")
{
  blockHash: "0x414049a38df383bfa0e71ad1b1618ff8d08b45ce16064c27aed205d905048e36",
  blockNumber: 10436,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 42000,
  from: "0x2de46430bc377ad5a1e4c2cdfea7baa1a6baf092",
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0xa6521114fe5c68ad252b163d7eac7415cd89c6259d8cdee47f681f14cefad6f0",
  to: "0xf74c6516c4f7c87c663f3aefce67d815fb1bf047",
  transactionHash: "0x6a66d2dbc1610e20405828fdbfbf7b028ec3ce5d20e3800267e0f99b70be1426",
  transactionIndex: 1
}
>
```

Comment: Did you start mining?

Comment: yes mining was started and going on..please see my answer...thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily after posting the question i just restarted the miner like below.

```
miner.stop()
miner.start(1)
```

and it worked as expected like below.

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(4, "ether")})
"0x95dd20206412f8598e6d996d2935ca834e4905c2d9909a4287c382dd9e3497d3"
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])

5.2438e+22
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
12000000000000000000
>
```

NOTE : I am not deleting this answer and posting my own answer so that somebody might get benefited.

Comment: Well, this solves the problem but doesn't answer why was it necessary to restart the miner.